# Просмотр RTF с помощью JAVA

Tags: java, rtf

У меня никак не получается открыть RTF документ с помощью JAVA. Я перечитал некоторую литературу и нашел `JTextPane`, `JEditorPane`, `JFormatedTextField`. Текст нужно только показать, поэтому я выбрал `JEditorPane`.

```
File InstructionFile = new File("Instruction.rtf");
tfInstruction = new JEditorPane("InstructionFile");
```

Текст пробовал задать с помощью файла, при инициализации `JEditorPane`, но такой вариант почему-то не работает.

Для `JEditorPane` в среде я нашел свойство `setDocument` - и кажется это именно тот метод, который мне нужно, но не имею понятия - как его использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для чтения RTF действительно можно использовать Swing'овские компоненты. Примеры [здесь](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html)

А вообще то чтобы не грузиться тяжелым Swing'ом можно просто использовать [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Там есть достаточно хорошо проработанный API для работы с офисными документами

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, нужный мне метод - read

    To show RTF file in JEditorPane use following code:

    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane ();
    editorPane.setEditorKit (new AdvancedRTFEditorKit ());
    editorPane.read (new FileInputStream (pathToRTFFile));

но почему этот код не работает

    tfInstruction = new JEditorPane ();
/ / JEditorPane.setEditorKit (new AdvancedRTFEditorKit ());
    tfInstruction.read (new FileInputStream ("Instruction.rtf"));

Ошибка указывает на метод Read, требует еще один параметр Object, подскажите что там нужно добавить